# How do we get to know if user joined with specific discord invite link in discord JS v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

i have this code and this doesn't work it sends else statement it doesn't really work how should i do it

```
module.exports = {
    name: "guildMemberAdd",
    run: async (member) => {


  const invites = await member.guild.invites.fetch(); // Fetch all invites for the server
  const usedInvite = invites.find(invite => invite.uses > (invite.uses - 1)); // Find the invite that was used to join the server
  
  if (usedInvite.code === 'https://discord.gg/8kPqr25d78') { // Check if the invite code matches your specific invite link
    console.log(`${member.user.tag} joined using the specific invite link.`);
  } else {
    console.log(`No its not it!`)
  }



    }
};
```